# Cardinal exponentiation formula

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Assume GCH and let $k,m$ be infinite cardinals. I would like to show that $k^m = \max \{ k,2^m \}$. We of course have $k=\beth_a$ and $m=\beth_b$ for ordinals $a,b$. If $a$ is a successor ordinal, then we may write

$$k^m = (2^{\beth_c})^{\beth_b} = 2^{\beth_c \cdot \beth_b} = 2^{\max \{ \beth_c, \beth_b \}} = \max \{ k,2^m \}$$

where $c$ is the predecessor of $a$. Can we do this when $a$ is not a successor ordinal? If so, how? Also, is GCH required here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true for singular cardinals. Especially under $\sf GCH$.

If $\kappa$ is a singular cardinal, and $\mu=\operatorname{cf}(\kappa)$ then $\mu<2^\mu=\mu^+<\kappa$ and $\kappa^\mu=\kappa^+$ (due to Koenig's theorem which tells us that $\kappa^{\operatorname{cf}(\kappa)}>\kappa$ for any infinite cardinal) which equals to neither $\kappa$ nor $2^\mu$.

There are many things to say about what we can prove, and what sort of $\sf GCH$ and similar assumptions are needed (more or less) for these things. You can find a lot of that in:

> M. Holz, K. Steffens, E. Weitz, **Introduction to Cardinal Arithmetic**.

Comment: Hi Asaf - I saw this book mentioned in the Advanced section of your "5 WH'S" piece. Although it looks pretty complicated, in it's Preface, it claims to be intended for undergrads. (Maybe the presentation is quite accessible.) What's your feelings? Thanks,

Comment: The first few chapter which cover the very basic things like ZFC, basic cardinal arithmetic, all the first part essentially, I think that's very nice exposition to the topic.